# How did the Ancient Greeks know that the circle method of finding square roots was mathematically valid? How do we know that?

Tags: geometry, math-history

The Ancients used this method. (or at least James Grime said in a numberphile video) To construct the square root of a number, draw an interval of length $a+1$, and then draw a semi-circle with the interval as the diameter. The perpendicular chord from the point where a and 1 meet has a length of the square root of $a$. I understand that this is the visual display of the geometric mean of $a$ and 1, but how were the Ancient Greeks certain that this method was valid?

Comment: Pythagorean theorem. Pythagoras was ancient and Greek.

Comment: Plus the fact, also known to the Greeks, that if $A$ and $B$ are the ends of a diameter of a circle, and $P$ is any other point on the circle, then $\triangle APB$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $\overline{AB}$.

Comment: By the way, Numberphile is full of nonsense. Much better to read books by actual mathematicians.

Answer (score 8):

The ancients didn't actually think of it as "finding a square root of a number", so they didn't prove that.

What they did was "find a square that has the same area as this rectangle", and/or "given line segments AB and CD, find a line segment EF such that the ratio of AB to EF is the same as the ratio of EF to CD".

The latter task can be proved using Thales' theorem and some similar triangles.

The former is the capstone proposition of book II of Euclid's *Elements*. Euclid's proof can be seen, for example, [here](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII14.html).

Comment: It's very easy to forget that there was a time when people didn't think about quantities in terms of abstract numbers. +1

Comment: @Araf Karagila: I think you (and Henning Makholm) are on dangerous ground making statements about how ancient Greek mathematicians thought. The theory of magnitudes and ratios expounded in Euclid's Elements certainly is a theory of abstract numbers. See http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookV/defV3.html for the starting point of this theory.

Comment: @RobArthan: _We_ recognize Eudoxus' ratios as matching our concept of number, but to the best of my knowledge the ancients refused to call them "numbers", and didn't even afford them being "magnitudes". And as your own link points out, the Greeks had no concept of _adding_ ratios.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: I was only using a convenient link to a translation of the relevant part of Euclid's Elements: Joyce's commentary is not mine. If you are encroaching on linguistic or philosophical criticism, then you really do need to be careful. You have just compounded your risk: "to the best of my knowledge, A refused to do B" is quite a strong statement; can you actually justify the instance of that statement you just made?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not all ancients, Ancient Indians were dealing in terms of abstract notions much before Greeks.

Answer (score 1):

That method is based in two facts:

- The altitude of a right triangle is the geometric mean of the segment that its foot determines on the hypothenuse.
- If a side of a triangle is the diameter of its circumscribed circle, the angle opposite to that side is right.

These facts were well-known to the ancient Greek mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where you can find it in Euclid:

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI13.html

The stack exchange content police tell me that links can go stale and insist I say more. So just in case the human race forgets proposition 13 of book VI of Euclid's Elements, I must explain that it tells you how to construct a geometric mean. I.e., given a line segment of length $a$ and a line segment of length $b$, it tells you how to construct a line segment of length $\sqrt{ab}$. If you take $b = a$, this tells you how to construct square roots.

Comment: Please summarise the link.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value. Please read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: Link summarised adequately?????

Comment: Thanks to the recent downvoters. What was the reason for your downvotes? Or are you too shy to say?